# I have a Dell Inspiron running ubuntu budgie 17.10. Recently after some updates the bluetooth device is no longer recognized

Tags: bluetooth

I have a Dell Inspiron running Ubuntu budgie 17.10 and after installing some updates there is no bluetooth, the bluetooth icon doesn't show up, and bluetooth manager says "no bluetooth adapter found", how can i fix this?

here is the output for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [1028:0810]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:1810]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci, wl
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:568a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 413c:301b Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.096643] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.950764] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin (v1.1)
[    8.540527] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    8.540536] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.540538] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.540539] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.540541] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    8.549686] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    8.549687] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    8.549687] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    8.549694] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    8.549694] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    8.549695] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    8.549711] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    8.549718] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[    8.549718] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    8.549718] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[    8.549719] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[    9.228458] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 api 5 features ignore-otp crc32 79cea2c7
[    9.490856] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    9.490857] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    9.490859] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: My **Qualcomm Atheros** works fine but doesn't have the extra `wl` driver that yours has. Can you run `lsmod | egrep -i 'ath10k_pci|wl'` and paste the output into your question? Also add the output from `uname -r`? Can you boot with grub **Advanced Options** and select an older kernel version that works ok?

Comment: I would do `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source` as it isn't needed but I doubt it will help bluetooth as the bluetooth chipset should show in `lsusb` results.  I would try installing new updates as a lot of changes are being made lately